# Search cases - find case by case role

Tags: civicase, search

I'm looking for a simple solution to allow staff to search for a case by **Case Role** in addition to **client name**.

currently the search cases screen  (civicrm/case/search?reset=1)  has only the client name / email or casetype , case status, start/end date.

Allowing to search for contact with a role on the case would have a number of uses.  e.g. find all cases supervised by a manager or referred by an external contact (where case supervisor and referrer are case roles)

Any thoughts on the best way to go about this.

thnx

civicrm 4.6.8
drupal 7.39

Answer (score 2):

Try the below steps-

1) Navigate to Search -> Advanced Search.

2) In Basic Criteria Tab, you can find a dropdown with the label `Display Results as` -> Select `Cases` in the dropdown input.

3) In Relationship Tab select the relationship type as the role. For eg.- `Case coordinator is`.

4) Optionally type the name in the `Target contact` textbox.

Hit Search -> Result shows the case list supervised by the contact.

Change the Display Results as to `Contacts` etc as per your requirement for the returned result.

Comment: Thank you for this seems obvious really.  

Going forward, and this may be to picky, but I would like to get these advanced search criteria (ie. search by case roles) added to a case search page.

Comment: would it be better to start from the advanced search from (and strip out everything but the relationship and case choices , or would it be better to start from the case search form and add in logic to search for case roles?  Or (as is probably the case), a different / better way altogether